# Can a PHP script block an entire server?

Tags: php, nginx

I have a simple PHP script that is called every minute by a cron job. The script updates the database with some external sources using file_get_contents and is running on a Nginx server.

The admin of the server on which the script is running, says that sometimes the script blocks the entire server. So I added a simple logging mechanism to see how long the script runs.
The result: Runtime is usually 1 second. Sometimes when the script fetches lots of data the runtime is a bit longer, but never longer than 20 seconds.

Here is a short version of the script:

```
//Logging
require "db_hweb_functions/KLogger.php";
$log = KLogger::instance(dirname(__FILE__) . "/db_hweb_log", KLogger::DEBUG);
$log->logInfo("++ Cron gestartet ++");  

$lockfile = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]). "/db_hweb_inc/lockFolder";

//Check if script is already running 
if(!is_dir($lockfile)) {
    // no lock present, so place one
    register_shutdown_function('unlock', &$log);
    mkdir($lockfile);

    require "NotORM/NotORM.php";
    //...// require some other files

    //MYSQL connect
    $dsn = "mysql:dbname=" . $dbName;
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pwd);
    $db = new NotORM($pdo);

    //...// Do something
}
else {
    echo "locked";
    $log->logInfo("## Cron: end (locked) ##");
}

function unlock(&$log) {
    $log->logInfo("## Cron: end ##");
    // remove the lock
    rmdir(realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]). "/db_hweb_inc/lockFolder");
}
```

The log file normally looks like this:

```
2013-07-09 15:18:01 - INFO --> ++ Cron started ++
2013-07-09 15:18:01 - INFO --> ## Cron end ##
2013-07-09 15:19:01 - INFO --> ++ Cron started ++
2013-07-09 15:19:01 - INFO --> ## Cron end ##
2013-07-09 15:20:01 - INFO --> ++ Cron started ++
2013-07-09 15:20:01 - INFO --> ## Cron end ##
```

But when the problem occurs the log file looks like this:

```
2013-07-09 15:28:54 - INFO --> ++ Cron started ++
2013-07-09 15:28:54 - INFO --> ## Cron end ##
2013-07-09 15:30:29 - INFO --> ++ Cron started ++
2013-07-09 15:30:29 - INFO --> ## Cron end ##
2013-07-09 15:30:57 - INFO --> ++ Cron started ++
2013-07-09 15:30:57 - INFO --> ## Cron end ##
```

The runtime is ok, but the cronjob executes the script at unusual times...

So: is it possible in a way that this script is blocking the entire server? Blocking means that e.g. http requests take forever and fail. The blocking problem occurs randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is not starting at unusuall times, but your have your loggin below this code

```
if(file_get_contents("db_hweb_inc/lock.txt") == "unlocked") {
    // no lock present, so place one
    register_shutdown_function('unlock');
    file_put_contents("db_hweb_inc/lock.txt", "locked");
```

So your log entry happens after those instructions are executed. if those instructions take longer time to execute then you will see the delayed entries. When your server admin says it block server he must be talking about disk i/o. because your reading and writing what could be a large file. Put your start loggin entry above these commands.

Comment: Thanks. I will place the loggin code above these commands. But the first lines only test if the script is already running using just a simple txt file with the string "unlocked" or "locked". So I don't think these lines cause the problem.

Comment: if there is heavy disk io readying the file can take sometime. there can be some other process thats heavy on disk. its always better to use a directory for your lock. Your current lock setup has too much overhead. 

`is_dir($lockfile)` //check to see if lock exist
`mkdir($lockfile)` //create a lock
`unlick($lockfile)` //remove lock

Comment: Thanks! I changed this. But I don't think, that this has caused the problems. Since the main task just uses the MySQL database with NOTORM, there shouldn't be any problems. Is there still the possibility that the script causes any problems? Even if the runtime is ok? I think the problems aren't caused by this script...